# Can't decrypt file encrypted with openpgp-php in gnupg

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg, pgp

I've created a public key and private key with OpenPGP-PHP, then I've imported them both into GnuPG, which won't import the public key without specifying the "--allow-non-selfsigned-uid" flag. Then, when I try to decrypt a file I get the following:

```
gpg --decrypt test.tif.asc 
Generated: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 11:12:28 -0500
gpg: unknown armor header: 
By:  <>
gpg: unknown armor header: 
Using: OpenPGP for PHP
gpg: unknown armor header: 
For: TEST
gpg: unknown armor header: 
gpg: encrypted with 512-bit RSA key, ID 519A1973, created 2016-02-25
      "TEST"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Wrong secret key used
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

But the key clearly exists:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys
/home/mike/.gnupg/secring.gpg
-----------------------------
sec    512R/519A1973 2016-02-25
uid                  TEST
```

I generate them with the PHP code:

```
$header = array(
        'Generated' => date( "r" ),
        'By' => "Test <test@test.com>",
        'Using' => "OpenPGP for PHP",
        'For' => "TEST"
           );

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$k = $rsa->createKey(512);
$rsa->loadKey( $k['privatekey'] );

$nkey = new OpenPGP_SecretKeyPacket(array(
            'n' => $rsa->modulus->toBytes(),
            'e' => $rsa->publicExponent->toBytes(),
            'd' => $rsa->exponent->toBytes(),
            'p' => $rsa->primes[1]->toBytes(),
            'q' => $rsa->primes[2]->toBytes(),
            'u' => $rsa->coefficients[2]->toBytes()
            ));

$uid = new OpenPGP_UserIDPacket( "TEST" );

$wkey = new OpenPGP_Crypt_RSA ($nkey );
$m = $wkey->sign_key_userid(array($nkey, $uid));

// Serialize private key
$private_bytes = $m->to_bytes();
$private_bytes = OpenPGP::enarmor( $private_bytes, "PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK", $header );

// Serialize public key message
$pubm = clone($m);
$pubm[0] = new OpenPGP_PublicKeyPacket($pubm[0]);
$public_bytes = OpenPGP::enarmor( $public_bytes, "PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK", $header );
```

And encrypt using:

```
$pgp_header = array(
        'Generated' => date( "r" ),
        'By' => "Test <test@test.com>",
        'Using' => "OpenPGP for PHP",
        'For' => "TEST"
        );

// Unarmor the public key for encrypting
$public_bytes = OpenPGP_Message::parse( OpenPGP::unarmor( $public_bytes, "PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK" ) );

echo encryptData( file_get_contents( "test.tif" ), "test.tif", $public_bytes, $pgp_header );

function encryptData( $data, $filename, $key, $header )
{
    $data = new OpenPGP_LiteralDataPacket( $data, array('format' => 'u', 'filename' => $filename ) );
    $encrypted = OpenPGP_Crypt_Symmetric::encrypt( $key, new OpenPGP_Message(array($data)) );

    return( OpenPGP::enarmor( $encrypted->to_bytes(), "PGP MESSAGE", $header ) );
}
```

But it seems like I'm definitely missing something somewhere. How can I get GnuPG to successfully decrypt my stuff?

Comment: "`$rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); $k = $rsa->createKey(512);`" Is it blocking RSA key sizes < 2048 bit? (It should be.)

Comment: @ScottArciszewski upped it to 2048 and still getting the same error! I'll keep it at 2048, though.

Comment: is the $public_bytes variable defined? `OpenPGP::unarmor( $public_bytes,`

Comment: Possibly related to this: https://github.com/singpolyma/openpgp-php/issues/27 Encryption does not work (throws an error and crashes GPA) with gpg using the generated keypair (the public key does not show up and the private key has just the cert capability). Also decryption says there is no valid encrypted PGP data. The encrypt/decrypt (E) capability is missing. Did you try gpg --edit-key keyid ? So you are not missing something, it is a problem with the generated keypair.

Answer (score 1):

First: try to encrypt with OpenPGP-PHP using a key generated with gpg -- does that work?  (It does for me locally.)

Next, make sure the key you are generating has the 0x04 "encrypt communications" key flag set (you will have to add a signature packet yourself for this, check out `lib/openpgp_crypt_rsa.php` on line 154 to see the default-generated packet if you do not supply one.

Also, there was a bug in the keygen example.  Please try the latest version.